# Ubuntu machine hang and whole LAN network stopped responding

Tags: networking, lubuntu

I am getting problems when my Ubuntu machine, it hangs(keyboard,mouse stopped responding, and screen looking blur). Also, the whole lan/wan network stopped responding.

**DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.04**
**DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.04"**

**Logs from /var/log/syslog file:**

```
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008034] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008047] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1614 at /build/linux-Y0uW00/linux-3.19.0/net/sched/sch_generic.c:303 dev_watchdog+0x1fe/0x210()
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008050] NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth1 (forcedeth): transmit queue 0 timed out
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008052] Modules linked in: cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nouveau snd_hda_intel snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep mxm_wmi snd_pcm wmi video snd_seq_midi ttm snd_seq_midi_event drm_kms_helper drm snd_rawmidi snd_seq edac_core i2c_algo_bit snd_seq_device edac_mce_amd snd_timer k8temp serio_raw snd soundcore shpchp 8250_fintek i2c_nforce2 tpm_infineon mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 pata_acpi hid_generic usbhid hid forcedeth pata_amd sata_nv floppy
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008089] CPU: 0 PID: 1614 Comm: firefox Tainted: P OE 3.19.0-33-generic #38-Ubuntu
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008091] Hardware name: Kobian KN6100M/KN6100M, BIOS 6.00 PG 06/01/2007
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008094] 00000000 00000000 f4c39ebc c16ec002 f4c39f00 f4c39ef0 c106177b c1995ee0
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008099] f4c39f1c 0000064e c1995f1c 0000012f c161ef9e 0000012f c161ef9e 00000000
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008104] f4e9b000 fffffc83 f4c39f08 c10617e3 00000009 f4c39f00 c1995ee0 f4c39f1c
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008109] Call Trace:
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008117] [] dump_stack+0x41/0x52
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008122] [] warn_slowpath_common+0x8b/0xc0
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008126] [] ? dev_watchdog+0x1fe/0x210
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008129] [] ? dev_watchdog+0x1fe/0x210
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008133] [] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x33/0x40
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008136] [] dev_watchdog+0x1fe/0x210
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008143] [] call_timer_fn+0x30/0xf0
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008148] [] ? __wake_up+0x3f/0x50
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008151] [] ? dev_graft_qdisc+0x70/0x70
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008155] [] run_timer_softirq+0x18c/0x2b0
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008158] [] ? dev_graft_qdisc+0x70/0x70
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008162] [] __do_softirq+0xec/0x230
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008166] [] ? cpu_callback+0x170/0x170
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008171] [] do_softirq_own_stack+0x26/0x30
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008173] [] irq_exit+0x95/0xa0
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008180] [] smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x38/0x50
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008183] [] apic_timer_interrupt+0x34/0x3c
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008186] ---[ end trace b31c809dae7ef8dc ]--- Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008193] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0 eth1: Got tx_timeout. irq status: 00000020
Dec 29 15:39:01 PC040 CRON[3351]: (root) CMD ( [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean) Dec 29 15:39:01 PC040 CRON[3350]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[1]: Created slice user-1000.slice.
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[1]: Starting user-1000.slice.
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[1]: Started Session 19 of user PC040.
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[1]: Starting Session 19 of user PC040.
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Reached target Timers.
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Starting Timers.
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Reached target Sockets.
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Starting Sockets.
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Reached target Paths.
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Starting Paths.
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Reached target Basic System.
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Starting Basic System.
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Reached target Default.
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Startup finished in 117ms.
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Starting Default.
Dec 29 15:49:04 PC040 dbus[583]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit' unit='console-kit-daemon.service'
Dec 29 15:49:04 PC040 systemd[1]: Starting Console Manager...
Dec 29 15:49:04 PC040 console-kit-daemon[3558]: missing action
Dec 29 15:49:04 PC040 dbus[583]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit'
Dec 29 15:49:04 PC040 systemd[1]: Started Console Manager. && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Comment: The fact that the whole LAN stops responding is concerning.  Is this host doing anything special on the network (ie, DHCP, routing, etc.)?

Comment: No DHCP is running in the network only static IP address assigned. Every Client Machine has IP based internet access controlled through WatchGaurd Firewall. and All the Linux, Windows, MAC machines have under AD Enviornment.